# Running Logux on Google Cloud Run doesn't find the running port

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run

While trying to get Logux running in Cloud Run, I get this error:

> Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable.

Even though the server is running an the Dockerfile is exposing the correct port (which is mapped in Cloud run as well).

[image]

The Dockerfile is located here: https://github.com/knownasilya/battle-chess/blob/main/Dockerfile

Note that the server runs https and ws on port 31337.

Comment: it is listening on 127.0.0.1 while Cloud Run expects the container to listen on 0.0.0.0 https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start

Comment: Yes, that was it! Would love if cloud run error mentioned this or pointed to some docs that did.

Comment: @FerreginaPelona if you post an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Sure! I've already posted my answer c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the Cloud Run [Troubleshooting docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start), if we get the message:

> Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable.

And we know our code/container is working as expected, we should check that the port that that Cloud Run will be checking correlates with the one used in our app and like in this case, that the container listens on 0.0.0.0 (all the net interfaces)

As well this is mentioned in the Cloud Run [Requirements doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port):

> The container must listen for requests on 0.0.0.0 on the port to which requests are sent. By default, requests are sent to 8080, but you can configure Cloud Run to send requests to the port of your choice. Cloud Run injects the PORT environment variable into the container. Inside Cloud Run container instances, the value of the PORT environment variable always reflects the port to which requests are sent. It defaults to 8080.